# How do I edit this question?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

Found this question: [Spring Security DWR not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589689/spring-security-dwr-not-working)

He has copied pasted the code 3 times. I know if I try to edit this, I'll be prosecuted for owning this question, because I've to remove 3 of them. And, to do a lot of changes to improve it.

So, what to do?

Comment: It's a humorous attempt at circumventing the quality control filter we have in place.  They were getting rejected by that when posting their question, so they repeated themselves until it was accepted.  Knowledge of our quality filter *alone* should give you a bit more in the way to identify and recognize these kinds of questions as they crop up.

Comment: oops. He did it bad. Do something

Comment: @Makoto yeh, I think the number of chars needs to be reduced

Comment: What do we do now that the original question in question is no longer in existence?

Comment: Haha, do nothing. Be happy thinking that it's solved already.

Comment: Could someone please add a screenshot of the question since it's deleted?

Comment: *"I know if I try to edit this, I'll be prosecuted for owning this question..."* Huh?

Comment: That's true @T.J.Crowder (You also know that). I learned it from my wrongs.

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean by that. It's probably not important that I know what you mean by it, but I don't.

Comment: @Toaster I'm also puzzled by the phrase TJ Crowder quoted.

Comment: I guess I'm too late for the party. The question has been removed but I would've loved to see how bad it was. Anyone with a screenshot?

Comment: Very funny @uom-pgregorio  :-P. Looks like you love to see StackOverflow dirty.haha

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Picture a couple of sentences with typos, and a large code block that contains several configuration files and some more text sentences with typos that aren't word wrapped and require scrolling horizontally. Then paste this all four times into a question.

Comment: @MrLister yikes! Although I think I'm also guilty of writing code blocks that will require horizontal scrolling. I prefer writing a statement in just a single line. Most developers will break them off into multiple lines for readability.

Comment: @Toaster you're the one who wrote it!  Can't you go back and explain what you meant, after *multiple people* have said they're confused?  Guess I'll never know what you actually meant...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would strongly advise just not editing it at all.  The question is just truly awful, and even removing all of the redundancies, would still be a terrible question when you're done.  Don't spend time editing questions that are going to be bad questions meriting deletion *even after you've finished editing them*.

Just downvote and vote for closure and move on to a question that can actually be salvaged.

Comment: 1. Haha, I can't downvote. 2. I do understand

Comment: It's an interesting philosophical point - does the question deserve three times the downvotes?

Comment: @MartinJames as you can only downvote a question once, pondering this question is the same as busy waiting -> A waste of precious resources.

Comment: Servy consider adding or flagging as needed closing, as OP doesn't have rep to downvote or close vote

Comment: @YvetteColomb or posting on meta, that usually does the trick ;)

Comment: It's gone now, BTW

Comment: @YvetteColomb Can you please tell me what is OP? I really don't know

Comment: @Toaster OP = Original Poster